# encontrar cadena en un json

Tags: python-3.x, json, regex

estoy trabajando con una api, que me devuelve un json.
Este es un ejemplo de la devolucion: https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/152i7meW31rjHqcSdG7k5LeVHcP1LpCZwK
Asi se veria el json sin convertir, esta a varios nivels el parametro "addr" que es el cual quiero capturar, la estructura del json cambia en funcion del numero de transaciones que halla realizado, solo quiero guardar todos los "addr" sin repeticiones.

```html
{
    "hash160":"2c333dd9eadbea36fd1a11cd4ba650e7d8f7ea17",
    "address":"152i7meW31rjHqcSdG7k5LeVHcP1LpCZwK",
    "n_tx":2,
    "total_received":1881203,
    "total_sent":1881203,
    "final_balance":0,
    "txs":[
    
    
    
    
        

{
   "ver":1,
   "inputs":[
      {
         "sequence":4294967295,
         "witness":"",
         "prev_out":{
            "spent":true,
            "spending_outpoints":[
               {
                  "tx_index":0,
                  "n":0
               }
            ],
            "tx_index":0,
            "type":0,
            "addr":"152i7meW31rjHqcSdG7k5LeVHcP1LpCZwK",
            "value":1881203,
            "n":1,
            "script":"76a9142c333dd9eadbea36fd1a11cd4ba650e7d8f7ea1788ac"
         },
         "script":"473044022042eee22f5224457207a010a04ee924a55fb8fe121fed607f187b3b482f3e2b2d02207ff5c78eec01cc3fc074e3d35c9e7d6314ecc8ee7699f0310bbdf12041ff30f501210292eed883cbe377dd36466987cadcbdd0726fa68976c2a16d46d1a985afc51bd0"
      }
   ],
   "weight":900,
   "block_height":628234,
   "relayed_by":"0.0.0.0",
   "out":[
      {
         "spent":true,
         "spending_outpoints":[
            {
               "tx_index":0,
               "n":0
            }
         ],
         "tx_index":0,
         "type":0,
         "addr":"19rmD6WL3V6hLCDPLAHtiwkAyGWdL1aThU",
         "value":750418,
         "n":0,
         "script":"76a914612a4ab4e8da20604d54e630635e4fd228ed4b8588ac"
      },
      {
         "spent":true,
         "spending_outpoints":[
            {
               "tx_index":0,
               "n":0
            }
         ],
         "tx_index":0,
         "type":0,
         "addr":"1Ex8BPw2sybFQ6zeJQCLLryAvd3N26VuDS",
         "value":1119085,
         "n":1,
         "script":"76a91499068189b337d354e2a8410f3609b76e38335f4288ac"
      }
   ],
   "lock_time":0,
   "result":-1881203,
   "size":225,
   "block_index":0,
   "time":1588217497,
   "tx_index":0,
   "vin_sz":1,
   "hash":"53843e19bec1e542fb633ecf3a7e43705db37d1fa97726f1c4cc2bc40d34b187",
   "vout_sz":2
},
    
    
    
    
        

{
   "ver":1,
   "inputs":[
      {
         "sequence":4294967295,
         "witness":"",
         "prev_out":{
            "spent":true,
            "spending_outpoints":[
               {
                  "tx_index":0,
                  "n":0
               }
            ],
            "tx_index":0,
            "type":0,
            "addr":"17WxuWAukKGHMnzWH5pfjwVNi6sW4XYKpM",
            "value":3049241,
            "n":0,
            "script":"76a914477b7c2406ff3ad255a49032fc8e874820b099d688ac"
         },
         "script":"483045022100db850bdab9dc58eb344381766833469584a099612f3742e1569c8bca6d32a4a202206704eab7aeb467336a6288a85eb6b4d638bd7c10507c806f4b944cf333abedc301210233753dcb98f75ca6c2305a03644faedd3463d280be5a9e920de33e56b0c402f2"
      }
   ],
   "weight":904,
   "block_height":628183,
   "relayed_by":"0.0.0.0",
   "out":[
      {
         "spent":true,
         "spending_outpoints":[
            {
               "tx_index":0,
               "n":0
            }
         ],
         "tx_index":0,
         "type":0,
         "addr":"1Ex8BPw2sybFQ6zeJQCLLryAvd3N26VuDS",
         "value":1152963,
         "n":0,
         "script":"76a91499068189b337d354e2a8410f3609b76e38335f4288ac"
      },
      {
         "spent":true,
         "spending_outpoints":[
            {
               "tx_index":0,
               "n":0
            }
         ],
         "tx_index":0,
         "type":0,
         "addr":"152i7meW31rjHqcSdG7k5LeVHcP1LpCZwK",
         "value":1881203,
         "n":1,
         "script":"76a9142c333dd9eadbea36fd1a11cd4ba650e7d8f7ea1788ac"
      }
   ],
   "lock_time":0,
   "result":1881203,
   "size":226,
   "block_index":0,
   "time":1588182513,
   "tx_index":0,
   "vin_sz":1,
   "hash":"1a47bffb806a04c3b88f766b38680131672e1577e5c01dabc428c3e3972e348e",
   "vout_sz":2
}
    ]
}
```

Lo que me gustaria hacer, es guardar todos los valores de "addr" en una array, para posteriomente trabajar con ellos.Primero probe con usar el formato clave valor pero, la estructura cambia en funcion de la consulta, por lo que me era imposible definir todas las diferentes opciones de structura, por lo que se me ocurrio convertir el json a cadena y buscar en la cadena os datos que quiero, pero la hacer esto me quede estancado,

```
 r = requests.get('https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/'+q)
    if r.status_code == 200 : 
        
        dat1 = r.text
        p = json.loads(dat1)
        get_addr = lambda: { 'addr':''}
        addrs= get_addr()

        for x in p:
            l = re.split(r'((\"addr\"\:)(\S+))', x)
            for i in enumerate(l):
                    if i == "addr":                
                        addrs['addr'].append(l[i+1].strip())
                        list_addr.append(addrs)
                        addrs = get_addr()
        json.dumps(list_addr)
        print(list_addr)
```

Me podrías hechar una mano ?

Comment: Hola. El idioma oficial de SOes es español, así que debo pedirte que traduzcas tu pregunta -incluyendo el título-. Gracias!

Comment: perdona fallo mio, no me fije en que servidor publique siempre usaba en EN. Lo modifico

Comment: No hay lío. Bienvenido!

Comment: Es complicado ayudarte sin saber los tipos de datos que tienes y los datos que quieres buscar. Estaría bien que edites la pregunta y pongas un ejemplo de ambas cosas así nos sería más fácil.

Comment: Habia puesto un enlace a un json de ejemplo, pero siguiendo tu consejo lo añado en la pregunta para que sea más directo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método

```
p = json.loads(dat1)
```

carga el JSON leido y lo deja convertido en diccionario.

Los valores en este diccionarios pueden ser valores numéricos, string, listas y otros diccionarios, los que a su vez pueden contener otras listas y diccionarios anidados.

Lo anterior significa que hay que hacer una función recursiva que recorra el diccionario buscando la llave. Si no es la llave deseada, entonces examina su contenido asociado. Si es una lista o diccionario, se llama recursivamente para revisar su contenido. Al retornar, devuelve una lista con los `addr` encontrados.

```
def examinar(iterable):
    """ Extrae todos los "addr" del diccionario.

    @param iterable: Un diccionario o lista.
    @return: Una lista con los valores de los "addr" encontrados.
    """
    addrs = []

    if type(iterable) is not str:
        if type(iterable) is dict:
            for k,v in iterable.items():
                if k == "addr":
                    addrs.append(v)
                else:
                    addrs.extend(examinar(v))
        elif type(iterable) is list:
            for x in iterable:
                addrs.extend(examinar(x))

    return addrs
```

**Comprobación**

```
URL = "https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/152i7meW31rjHqcSdG7k5LeVHcP1LpCZwK"
respuesta = requests.get(URL)
if respuesta.status_code == 200:
    p = json.loads(respuesta.text)
    for addr in examinar(p):
        print(addr)
```

produce

```
152i7meW31rjHqcSdG7k5LeVHcP1LpCZwK
19rmD6WL3V6hLCDPLAHtiwkAyGWdL1aThU
1Ex8BPw2sybFQ6zeJQCLLryAvd3N26VuDS
17WxuWAukKGHMnzWH5pfjwVNi6sW4XYKpM
1Ex8BPw2sybFQ6zeJQCLLryAvd3N26VuDS
152i7meW31rjHqcSdG7k5LeVHcP1LpCZwK
```

Lo que concuerda con el resultado de grep sobre el mismo archivo:

```
candid@gear:~/Downloads$ grep \"addr\" 152i7meW31rjHqcSdG7k5LeVHcP1LpCZwK.json 
            "addr":"152i7meW31rjHqcSdG7k5LeVHcP1LpCZwK",
         "addr":"19rmD6WL3V6hLCDPLAHtiwkAyGWdL1aThU",
         "addr":"1Ex8BPw2sybFQ6zeJQCLLryAvd3N26VuDS",
            "addr":"17WxuWAukKGHMnzWH5pfjwVNi6sW4XYKpM",
         "addr":"1Ex8BPw2sybFQ6zeJQCLLryAvd3N26VuDS",
         "addr":"152i7meW31rjHqcSdG7k5LeVHcP1LpCZwK",
```

Comment: Solucion sencilla y muy efectiva gracias!!